# Figure of speech name

Tags: english, terminology, semantics

Is there a name for a situation where a word is not needed because a the previous word doesn’t require it?

Example: heart attacks are harmful for your health. “harmful” makes no sense there because heart attacks are not beneficial.

Comment: Redundancy? I wouldn't call it redundant here, though, "heart attacks are […] for your health" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Redundant would be “a harmful heart attack”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for pleonasm.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm